# How To Run Connection Provisioner On Every Terraform Apply

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, connection

I have created a  null resource  with connection and file provisioner .  I want the connection and file provisioner to run on very terraform apply . How can we make the connection provisioner run on every terraform apply without recreating the dependent ec2 resource . I have tried  marking the null resource as tainted , which does run the file provisioner but not the connection provisioner. Below is my code for the same .

```
  resource "null_resource" "resource_null" {
      depends_on = [aws_instance.public-ec2]
      triggers = {
        aws_public_ip = aws_instance.public-ec2.public_ip
        aws_ec2_key_pair = tls_private_key.tls_pk.private_key_pem
        always_run = timestamp()
      }

     connection {
         type = "ssh"
         host        = self.triggers.aws_public_ip
         user        = "ec2-user"
         password    = ""
         private_key = self.triggers.aws_ec2_key_pair
         }


    provisioner "file" {

    source      = "./myKey.pem"
    destination = "/tmp/myKey.pem"
    }

   provisioner "remote-exec" {
      inline = ["sudo chmod 400 /tmp/myKey.pem"]
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could to add the `uuid()` terraform function to use an activation  [trigger](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/null/latest/docs/resources/resource#triggers) for null resource or provisioner for each terraform apply: [uuid function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/uuid)

So, you can try to add inside the `null_resource`:

```
triggers {
    key = "${uuid()}"
  }
```